# What determines the relevant surface area of the electrical conduction?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, electrochemistry

I'm using a four-probe system (nextron) to measure the voltage between the two points of my sample. Sample has a cylindrical shape and it's placed on its base inside the instrument. The probes are placed on its upper surface (the base of the cylinder).

From the voltage measured, I'd like to calculate specific resistance. Resistance is calculated from the Ohm's law (current is kept constant). To calculate specific resistance, sample geometry is required. From what I learned, the relationship between the two is given by: $$R = \rho \frac {l}{A}$$

This relationship holds for the current flowing in the axial direction of the cylinder (where the cross section of the conductor is circular and doesn't change in the direction of the current flow). However, in my case, I'm not able to place the sample like that in the instrument and the question becomes: What am I actually measuring?

After discussing this with my colleagues and supervisor, I was told that I'm measuring the surface specific resistance not bulk. The thing is, my sample isn't very thin and also it seems that the current between two points is flowing through a surface area which changes in the current flow direction.

Generally, when we connect the probes of any voltage measuring device (four point probe or normal voltmeter) between two points of the conductor, how do we know what surface area of the conductor is relevant for the electrical conduction?

I think that the whole area (mass) of the conductor is relevant between the two points since it's the same material (potential is the same over the whole cross sectional area perpendicular to the current flow) and therefore I don't think that the surface specific resistance is measured here. Moreover, I think I need to create the sample such that the surface area doesn't change in the direction of current flow (small cylinder placed on its side or a rectangular shape). Otherwise, I don't know how to get a relationship between resistance and specific resistance. If you know, do give me a reference.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Why would your measurement cause current to flow only on the surface? DC current will flow through the insides of the body.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. My supervisor claims that.

Comment: Based on what? It is contrary to the usual behaviour. Homogeneous ohmic conductor will conduct current through its inside, the surface only provides boundary for the current which it can't cross.

Comment: Don't really get what he is up to. Could be that we misunderstood each other.